Can I run ducting straight up from a bathroom exhaust fan?
I got to work on remodeling my bathroom after finding mold in the drywall. Previous owners did not have an exhaust fan in the bathroom, however, there is a roof vent installed directly above where the light fixture and wiring was.
My question is: Can I buy a bathroom exhaust fan and vent it straight up to the roof above where the fan would be installed? Or will I need to cut a new hole in the ceiling drywall so I can have some length of a horizontal run of ductwork before exiting through the roof vent?



What are we looking at through the round hole?

This something that could be ok or a code violation depending on location.
I do suspect that a fan was in that location in the past.
In my area there is no problem running a duct straight vertically to exit the roof. Usually the side discharge fans will need about a foot of run horizontally before turning up.  I actually have seen bath fans that have the duct attached at the top and exit straight vertically.
You may need to consult your local building dept. regarding the local rule.

Awesome, this is exactly the insight I was looking for. Thank you

You can, I had one like that. You should be absolutely sure no rain or snow can enter the vent because it will drain back through the fan. Not a huge electrical risk but annoying to walk under.
